# How to change SKActions in real time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I have a guessing game. It has main scene with animations and 4 levels on it. By default only first level is unlocked and it has it's animations that are going constantly. When player finishes first level I'm passing the integer to the main scene to change second level's texture and to run animation on it too. All animations are done on a background, so I can't just add action on a second level. I need to stop background animation that represents only one unlocked level and run animation with two open levels right away. In general, passing an integer is working good, textures are changer when they need to, but whatever I tried – I can't replace first animation with second while project is running. I've read here that I should "kill" first animation and only then add new one. Well, it didn't worked. I feel that I'm mistaken with actions, but I dont know how. Here is my code:

```
    let action1 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(firstArray, timePerFrame: 0.1))
    let action2 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(secondArray, timePerFrame: 0.2))
    let action3 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(thirdArray, timePerFrame: 0.2))
    let action4 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(fourthArray, timePerFrame: 0.2))

    if !hp1open {
    background.runAction(action1, withKey: "act1")
    }else if hp1open == true {
        background.removeActionForKey("act1")
        background.runAction(action2, withKey: "act2")
    }else if hp1open == true && rp1open == true {
        background.removeActionForKey("act2")
        background.runAction(action3, withKey: "act3")
    }else if hp1open == true && rp1open == true && fp1open == true {
        background.removeActionForKey("act3")
        background.runAction(action4, withKey: "act4")
    }
```

hp1open, rp1open and so on – booleans that I use to change level texture to "unlocked". I already tried to use nodes themselves and those integers that I'm passing between scenes instead of them. It's not working, so I think my problem is SKActions. Please, help!

Comment: You "think"? Check by adding logs or breakpoints in the different parts of your if-elses to check which part is actually run (and the values of the booleans). Once you know, you will be able to determine where the problem actually is.

Comment: @jcaron I already checked everything else except SKActions. If boolean is changed to `true` it makes everything right except actions

Comment: So you are sure that when you expect it, it does actually run the `removeActionForKey:` and the `runAction:withKey:` methods?

Comment: Note that you could keep the same key and simply overwrite the previous action.

Comment: @jcaron I figured out my main problem. I use integerForKey and it works when player opens new level. But when he just enters the game, there are no integers, because he didn't play yet. I need to save it somehow so player would not loose his progress

Comment: So your issue was indeed that your booleans were incorrect, and that you were not executing the right code?

Comment: @jcaron not really. problem was with NSUserDefaults. They were not saving progress, so I made a score-highscore scheme where score is an integerForKey that was passed now and highscore is the highest number. And saving a highscore untill score will be greater. Then highscore will overwrite itself.

Comment: Which is just a convoluted way to say the problem was not in the code you posted, but somewhere else entirely.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, I'm not denying that :)